# Convert 2D numpy array to a 1D array of my own dtype

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, dtype

Suppose I have a 2D numpy array of `dtype=np.float`. Let's say the shape is `(n, 4)`.

I want to convert that array to a new array of a new dtype: `new_type = np.dtype([('a', np.float, 1), ('b', np.float, 1), ('c', np.float, 2)])`, i.e., type with 3 fields ('a', 'b', 'c') of type float where the first field has 1 element, the second has 1 element and the third has 2 elements.

I can't find a way to convert the 2D array into a 1D array of my new dtype (so each element as 3 fields with overall 4 elements that correspondence to the matrix rows) without using loops.
I've tried using the `astype()` function but it converts each element to the new type instead of each row as I wish.

For example I have the array:

```
array([[1., 2., 3., 4.],[5., 6., 7., 8.]])
```

and I want to get

```
array([(1., 2., [3., 4.]), (5., 6., [7., 8.])], dtype=[('a', '<f8'), ('b', '<f8'), ('c', '<f8', (2,))]
```

Comment: Look at https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.rec.html#module-numpy.lib.recfunctions, esp. `unstructured_to_structured`

Comment: Thanks @hpaulj, that's what I've looked for!